# Bayer Elanco Advocate topical treatment for Deworming cats

Tags: cats, medicines, parasites

I have always used oral medication for deworming my adult cat but I recently learnt about "Bayer Elanco Advocate" - which is a topical treatment for worms.

[image: Advocate]

I always thought topical treatment is only for ticks/fleas (which is not a problem where I am, so I don't use any tick/flea treatment). I was wondering if anyone here has used this for deworming & if it works well? Also what is the frequency of using this? Is it similar to oral deworming frequency?

Comment: Is it possible, that the cats make an oral treatment out of it, by grooming their fur?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't used this specific brand, but I use topical treatment for intestinal parasites on both of my cats and it works great. One cat is a barn cat, living mostly outside and eating mice, which is how she gets infected with worms regularily. If this type of trearment wouldn't work, I would definitely notice.

A topical treatment is basically a toxin that gets absorbed through the skin. **You must never treat a cat with a topical treatment designed for dogs! It might kill them.** You should also use the right dosage for the weight of your cat.

To treat your cat you unscrew the cap (some caps don't come off and it looks like they're still closed, but they create an opening in the cap when twisted). Then you should part the fur on the back of the neck (best done by petting) to ensure the treatment touches the skin. Then hold the bottle upside down against the neck skin and squeeze until it's empty. That's it. You may want to wear a glove to massage the liquid into the skin a little bit. And wash your hands afterwards.

You'll have to read how long one treatment lasts on the package. It may differ for different brands, but typical is 2 - 4 months. And the cats should not lick the liquid from their fur. That's why it's applied on the neck, where they cannot reach.

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you tell me which brand you used?

Comment: Brand recommendations are out of scope here. Ask your vet.